# Firebaseui-web callback on successful sign-in isn't called

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) (v2) in my React (15.3.1) project, but its successful signin callback isn't working. I know the test user is signing in correctly since looking in the Firebase console I see a new user get added with a 'signed in' property of the current date/time. This is the relevant code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
      modalIsOpen: false,
      loggedIn: false,
      currentUser: null
    };

    this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    this.uiConfig = {
      'signInSuccessUrl': 'http://localhost:3333',
      'signInOptions': [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ],
      'signInFlow': 'popup',
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
          alert("Signed in as "+currentUser + " with credential " + credential);
          this.setState({"modalIsOpen": false});
        }.bind(this)
      }
    };
```

I've put breakpoints in the signInSuccess function but they never trip. I get no console errors either.

edit: reverting to v1.0.0 fixed my issue (with identical code), so it's a problem with v2.0.0. I read the docs on their page and I didn't see any difference in their implementation to mine, so I don't see why switching to v2 would break the code above, but it certainly seems to be doing that.

Comment: Try firebase code in `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor`.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara Tried that, didn't change anything, same result.

Comment: Are you calling `this.ui.start()` method somewhere?

Comment: Yep, I have the login buttons in a react-modal window. When it opens it calls `  afterOpenModal = () => {
    this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', this.uiConfig)
  }`. I'm assuming this works because I get the login buttons, can click any of them, and see the user appear in the firebase user console.

Comment: Did you try other callback `uiShown()`?

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara yep, that callback works. But for some reason the other one still doesn't. And my console is still showing latest 'signed in' date as today for that test account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145296/discussion-between-tharaka-wijebandara-and-ironwaffleman).